# Change keyboard bindings for the Workspace switcher for Linux Mint 17 “Qiana” - Xfce (64-bit)

Tags: linux-mint

The Workspace switcher is hard-coded to `Ctrl-F1` .. `Ctrl-F4` in Mint. I would like to change that to `Super-F1` ..., but I do not even know where that is configured.

Is this possible? How? With the keyboard editor (gui), there is no option to set the Workspace switcher shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

This is configured in Setting / Window Manager / Keyboard.

Unfortunately I cannot do anything with default shortcuts in Mint 17.1 Xfce - see my answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152897/cannot-change-global-keyboard-shortcuts-in-linux-mint-xfce) to show how I modified it manually.

Comment: The link is to another SE site, but it's better for answers to be self-contained.  This doesn't really contain a solution without what's at the other end of the link.  You could post this as a comment, but to keep it an answer, consider including the essential information here and keep the link for attribution.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you go to the settings manager, key board, and go to application shortcuts.
PS. You also helped me to know the key binding, I don't understand the command based shortcut manager too well, thanks!